# how to submit button click by text link

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait, selenium4

I am trying submit form using selenium, but submit button isn't working , How can I submit button through `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button\[@type="submit"\]').click()` this isn't working for me.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
       
driver.get('https://splendour.themerex.net/contact/')
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Get In Touch").click()`
```

Advance thanks

Comment: The "button" on that page is not a button, but an ``input``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I guess you are using Selenium 4. If so `find_element_by_*` are no more supported there. You need to use the modern syntax of `driver.find_element(By.` as folllowing.
2. You need to introduce `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` to wait for element to become clickable.

The following code works

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://splendour.themerex.net/contact/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='submit']"))).click()
```